# How can I increment content of object and it's properties and properties value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, increment

```
var groups = new Truck([
    {id: num, content: `Truck&nbsp;${num}`}
]);
```

In a constructor, I am trying to increment the whole object inside an array on a button click. I also want to increase the `Number(num)` of the `id` and `content`. And, I want to use a button for this whole process, when I click a button an array should add one more object inside itself along with the number incremented, like this:

```
var groups = new Truck([
    {id: 1, content: `Truck&nbsp;1`},
    {id: 2, content: `Truck&nbsp;2`},
    {id: 3, content: `Truck&nbsp;3`},
    {id: 4, content: `Truck&nbsp;4`}
]);
```

Comment: You should show the code for your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the class constructor to declare an id and an array.
2. Declare an `add` method that creates a new object based on the current id, pushes it in to the array, and then increments the id.
3. Create an instance of `Truck`.
4. Create a button, and attach a listener to it that calls a function that calls `add` on the instance, and then logs it.

```js
class Truck {

  constructor() {
    this.id = 1;
    this.arr = [];
  }
  
  add() {
    this.arr.push({
      id: this.id,
      content: `Truck ${this.id}`
    });
    ++this.id;
  }

}

const group = new Truck();

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  group.add();
  console.log(group);
}
```

```html
<button>Add new object</button>
```